# Cómo hago para que no se note el corte del audio [mediaRecorder]

Tags: javascript, jquery, blob

No sé si lo he hecho mal, pero he creado una función que graba un segundo y lo mete en un blob y lo reproduce, el problema es que se nota demasiado el entre corte, qué puedo hacer?

los blob van al server y se reproducen ya que es parte de la secuencia de un live de video...}

Qué puedo hacer para solucionar este problema? o si hay otra manera de hacerlo, sacar cada cierto tiempo la grabación sin tener que darle 'click' al botón, o que el blob no cambie, no sé, no encuentro solución

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title>Grabación</title>
</head>
<body class="body-us">
<audio id="pista" autoplay="autoplay" controls></audio>
<br/>
<br/>
<input id="grabar" type="button" value="Grabar" />
<input id="parar" type="button" value="Parar" style="visibility:hidden;"/>


<script type="text/javascript">
if (navigator.mediaDevices) {

  var chunks = [];
  var audio = document.getElementById('pista');
  var grabar = document.getElementById('grabar');
  var parar = document.getElementById('parar');


  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
  })
    .then(function(stream) {

    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    grabar.onclick = function() {
      if (mediaRecorder.state != 'inactive') {
        return;
      }
      grabar.disabled = true;   
      mediaRecorder.start();
      
    }

    parar.onclick = function() {
      if (mediaRecorder.state == 'inactive') {
        return;
      }
      grabar.disabled = false;    
      mediaRecorder.stop();
      mediaRecorder.start();
    }

    mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
      audio.controls = true;
      var blob = new Blob(chunks, {
        'type': 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus'
      });
      
      chunks = [];
      audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    }

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
      chunks.push(e.data);
    }
  })
    .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
   var tiempo = 1000;
   var interval = setInterval(function() {
   $('#parar').trigger('click');
   }, tiempo);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner más código? ¿Qué fichero estás cargando? ¿De qué tipo es el parámetro stream?

Comment: Puedes comprobar con la función ```MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/ogg; codecs=opus')``` si el codec está soportado por el navegador donde estás realizando la prueba. Si te devuelve *true* entonces haría falta más contexto para ver que está fallando

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, pero ahora tengo otro problema, ya he actualizado la pregunta.

Comment: al reproducir los chunks (blob) desde el server hay cortes?

Comment: Sí, sucede lo mismo

Comment: fijate abriendo el archivo en un editor de audio si el corte es parecido a esto https://pasteboard.co/IpYOYZq.png ( sucede en chrome, firefox lo maneja mejor )

Comment: otra prueba que podes hacer es ser mas estricto con los constraints onda: `audio: { echoCancellation: false, autoGainControl: false, noiseSuppression: false, sampleRate: sampleRate, numOfChannels: numChannels, sampleSize: bitDepth, }, video: false,` como los filtros tienen diferentes nombres en diferentes navegadores tal vez te convenga usar un adapter https://github.com/webrtchacks/adapter ( incluir el script https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js antes de tu script así no tenes q especificar `googAutoGainControl` sino simplemente `autoGainControl` )

Comment: @PabloLozano por lo general usando un constraint `audio:true` el stream es pcm raw 48kHz stereo 32 bits float  little endian ( aunque algunas versiones canary levantan el samplerate a 96kHz, los mics integrados aún siendo mono exponen 2 channels pero puede variar según el OS )